# Android Hilt provide object with dynamic property

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt, android-paging-3, android-paging-library

I am using [PagingSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingSource). From the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data) here is an example of paging source class implementation.

```
class ExamplePagingSource(
    val backend: ExampleBackendService,
    val query: String
) : PagingSource<Int, User>() {
........
........
```

In ViewModel i have setup flow of paging data this way

```
val flow = Pager(
  PagingConfig(pageSize = 20)
) {
  ExamplePagingSource(backend, query)
}.flow
  .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

Now if I want `Hilt` to provide `ExamplePagingSource` dependency how can I do that?

`ExamplePagingSource` took `query` in the constructor which changes every search action, I always have to provide a new instance of `ExamplePagingSource`.

One way could be to initialize `ExamplePagingSource` with `ExampleBackendService` and set `query` by setter every time. But this will not work if I call [PagingDataAdapter.refresh()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingDataAdapter#refresh()) for swipe refresh action and it throws exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: An instance of PagingSource was
> re-used when Pager expected to create a new instance.Ensure that the
> pagingSourceFactory passed to Pager always returns a new instance of
> PagingSource.

So how can I config `Hilt` so that `Hilt` can provide `ExamplePagingSource` as a dependency

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of dagger's [assisted injection](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/assisted-injection.html). The `query` will be `@Assisted` and you will have to pass it to `create` function, but `ExampleBackendService` and everything else will be provided by dagger.

```kotlin
class ExamplePagingSource @AssistedInject constructor(
    val backend: ExampleBackendService,
    @Assisted val query: String
)

@AssistedFactory
interface ExamplePagingSourceFactory {
    fun create(query: String): ExamplePagingSource
}

@HiltViewModel
class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val exaplePagingSourceFactory: ExamplePagingSourceFactory,
) : ViewModel() {
    val flow = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 20)) {
        exaplePagingSourceFactory.create(query)
    }
}
```